# Django Rest Framework - Custom serializer field does not appear in attrs dict when using "create" method

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I created a `ModelSerializer` and want to add a custom field which does not belong to my model but is shown as part of serialized data when retrieving it and behave as writeable field when `create` method is called.

I have a problem with `validate` method used on data passed in `POST` method. The field that does not belong to my model does not appear in `attr` dict when passed to `validate` method.

The field I want is `teams` and when model instance already exists, I want this field to use method to retrieve result data (this works fine) and when the `create` method is called I want it to be a writeable field. Is this possible in any way?

```
class MatchDaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #Validate if teams field exists in POST data to avoid creating Matchdays with no Players
    def validate(self, ):
        if not "teams" in attrs:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"teams": "This field is required"})
        return attrs


    #Serializer Fields
    matches = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    teams = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MatchDay
        fields = [
            'id',
            'date',
            'matches',
            'teams',
        ]


    #Returns match counter
    def get_matches(self, obj):
        if not hasattr(obj, 'id'):
            return None
        if not isinstance(obj, MatchDay):
            return None
        return obj.match_counter

    #Return teams with list of players ids
    def get_teams(self, obj):
        tickets_dict = MatchDayTicket.objects.filter(matchday=obj).values('player_id', 'team')

        teams_dict = {
            "blue":[],
            "orange":[],
            "colors":[],
        }

        for ticket in tickets_dict:
            if ticket.get('team') == "blue":
                del ticket['team']
                teams_dict["blue"].append(ticket)

            if ticket.get('team') == "orange":
                del ticket['team']
                teams_dict["orange"].append(ticket)

            if ticket.get('team') == "colors":
                del ticket['team']
                teams_dict["colors"].append(ticket)
        return teams_dict


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        teams_data = self.initial_data.get('teams')

        matchday = MatchDay.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for team, players in teams_data.items():
            for player_data in players:
                player = Player.objects.get(id=player_data['id'])
                MatchDayTicket.objects.create(matchday=matchday, player=player, team=team)
        return matchday
```

I tried to find information in the documentation but can't find anything about the different behavior of the fields depending on usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but as I'm creating my first project in drf I'm not sure if it follows the convention. I use `initial_data` to acces data in POST request.